# How to get last executed query from Linq in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, linq, datacontext

I want to find in query it throws error. below is the code

```
try{
if (list1 != null)
            {
                foreach (cca item in list1)
                {
                      db.CCAs.InsertOnSubmit(item);
                 }
            }
if (list2 != null)
            {
                foreach (cca1 item1 in list2)
                {
                      db.CCAs1.InsertOnSubmit(item1);
                 }
            }
 db.SubmitChanges();
}
catch
{
}
```

In catch, I want to get which query throwed error. I want to retrieve only the affected query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you can divide saving operation like:

```
try
{
    if (list1 != null)
    {
        foreach (cca item in list1)
        {
            db.CCAs.InsertOnSubmit(item);
        }
        db.SubmitChanges(); 
    }
}
catch 
{
    //write error into log 
}
try
{
    if (list2 != null)
    {
        foreach (cca1 item1 in list2)
        {
            db.CCAs1.InsertOnSubmit(item1);
        }

        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
catch
{
    //write error into log
}
```

Now, you need 2 db calls, but it allows easily handle exceptions.

**UPD**
I'm not sure, but you can try like this in your catch block:

```
catch (YourExpectedExceptionType ex)
{
     //write into log for e.g
     _log.Write(ex.InnerExeption);
     _log.Write(ex.Source);
}
```

Comment: It takes more time if i set db calls for each list. Each list has more than 5000 records to update.

Comment: Try catching DataException and find the source table which causes exception.